# How can i add a line-break on a costume tooltip?

Tags: css

How can i add a line-break on a costume tooltip? Be it a css or jquery one , i am not sure how to do it , it's simple with native tooltips by using `&#13;` but that doesn't work with a costume one , and that makes displaying some info hard , for example:

```
Name:John Smith
Age:15
Hair-Color:Green
.
.
.
```

So what would be the solution?

Comment: Yes , a line break.In some languages u can use /n for that i thought it would be the same for jQuery but no.

Comment: @aleksXPO This is not related to jQuery, but to displaying the line breaks, which means you will have to use some CSS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use a simple line break `&#13;` or `\n` , you have to set `white-space: pre;` to preserve line breaks and white space. Or you may transform each `&#13;` to a line break HTML tag `<br />` in the backend or via JS.

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/white-space

Comment: Nice info about white-space: pre;

Answer (score 1):

In javascript there are two ways you can do this:

Using the newline `\n` character in your string:

`var tooltipstring = "John Smith \n Age:15 \n Hair-Color:Green";`

Or by adding a new line in the string and escaping it correctly with a backslash `\`:

```
var tooltipstring = "John Smith \
Age:15 \
Hair-Color:Green";
```